# Parse.com как связать данные с TableViewCell и ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, parse.com

У меня TableViewCell имеет название и изображение.От него идет переход во ViewController который представляет данные о обьекте это информацию о матче, описание и название , изображение .Вот как связать чтоб данные по id отображались.Сделал через  for in  object , данные ячейки меняются по кругу.Без For in  данное одно в разных ячейках отображается.Вот мой код.

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class DetailTennisViewController: UIViewController {



    @IBOutlet weak var imageTennis: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var outClose: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTennis: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var textTennis: UITextView!

    @IBOutlet weak var progTennis: UILabel!

    @IBAction func closeOut(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)

    }
    var tenises : Tennis?

    func configureButton()
    {
        outClose.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * outClose.bounds.size.width


        outClose.clipsToBounds = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadTennis()
        configureButton()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loadTennis () {


        let qwery = PFQuery(className: "tennis")


        qwery.getFirstObjectInBackground() { (object,error) ->Void in
            if error == nil {

                self.textTennis.text = object!["textTen"] as? String
                self.progTennis.text = object!["progTen"] as? String
                self.titleTennis.text = object!["titleTen"] as? String
                let imageFile = object!["tenImage"] as? PFFile
                imageFile?.getDataInBackground() { (data:Data?, error:Error?)->Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        if let imageData = data {
                            self.imageTennis.image = UIImage(data: imageData)



                    }

            }

        }

            }



    }



}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Далее, имея массив объектов, получаете нужный объект используя `IndexPath`.

Пример:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentified", for: indexPath)
        let object = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = object.title
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: а у меня есть связь , такая.Может нужно создать функцию? Знаете , Вы мне отвечали уже.По вопросу parse.com.ТАк я убрал for in ,и у меня теперь открываются ячейки, но в них один тот же фрагмент отображается

Comment: Вы должны из вашей таблицы передать нужный объект в котроллер, и уже на основании этого объекта строить вью.